# How can I get the Primary Key Field and Default Value of an Entity in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My database designer did not use the standard "Id" for Primary Key fields in my database, so I need to find the following things for my generic repository that I am writing.

- Primary Key Name
- Primary Key CLR Type
- Primary Key CLR Type Default value

I am trying to take the Generated scaffolding code that looks like the following and make a generic repository:

```
    public void InsertOrUpdate(Entity entity)
    {
        if (entity.EntityID == default(int))
        {
            // New entity
            _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity (TODO:  Wont add the whole graph of things)
            _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

I have found the Primary Key Name by doing the following:

```
    public string FindPrimaryKey()
{
    var objectSet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Entity>();
    string keyName = objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    return keyName;
}
```

I am close to getting the Primary Key CLR Type with the following code:

```
  public string FindPrimaryKeyType()
        {
            var objectSet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Entity>();
            string keyType = objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.TypeUsage.EdmType.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
            var keyType2 = from m in objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers
                select m.TypeUsage.EdmType;
            return "";
        }
```

And I can see the ClrType when debugging the code above, but I haven't been able to figure out  how to get the Type from ClrType:

[image: VS 2013 Debug screen shot]

So, please help  me figure out how to get the ClrType, or another better idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You already got the key names that mean the property names, just use reflection to get the property type.

```
var objectSet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Entity>();
var keyNames = objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray();
```

To get the clr types.

```
var types = keyNames.Select(keyName => typeof(Entity).GetProperty(keyName).PropertyType).ToArray();
```

To get the default values.

```
var defaultValues = types.Select(type => type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null).ToArray();
```

## update

Wrap everything in a class

```
public class EntityHelper<Entity> where Entity :class
{
    private DbContext _context;
    public EntityHelper(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public string[] FindPrimaryKeyNames()
    {
        var objectSet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Entity>();
        var keyNames = objectSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name).ToArray();
        return keyNames;
    }
    public Type[] FindPrimaryKeyTypes()
    {
        var keyNames = FindPrimaryKeyNames();
        var types = keyNames.Select(keyName => typeof(Entity).GetProperty(keyName).PropertyType).ToArray();
        return types;
    }
    public object[] FindPrimaryKeyDefaultValues()
    {
        var types = FindPrimaryKeyTypes();
        var defaultValues = types.Select(type => type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null).ToArray();
        return defaultValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great @yuliam-chandra, is there a way I could put the last part or all of this in  a function?  I have put the first two parts in functions, but ... Not sure how to do the last one with Generics.  The "<Entity>" should really be a type T for a generic repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any direct approach to map from the `EdmType` exposed by the metadata of your model back to the native .Net `Type`. A hybrid approach is offered by Yuliam that switches to .Net refection to resolve the type.

If you want to stick with Entity Framework metadata you could do the mapping yourself as shown in the following code sample. This is code I have lying around that was inspired from the following SO question: [Is there a mapper to/from EDM/OData types to CLR types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154819/is-there-a-mapper-to-from-edm-odata-types-to-clr-types)

```
private static Type GetTypedEdmValue(EdmType type)
{           
    switch (type.FullName)
    {
        case "Edm.String": return typeof(string);
        case "Edm.Byte": return typeof(byte);
        case "Edm.SByte": return typeof(sbyte);
        case "Edm.Int16": return typeof(short);
        case "Edm.Int32": return typeof(int);
        case "Edm.Int64": return typeof(long);
        case "Edm.Double": return typeof(double);
        case "Edm.Single": return typeof(float);
        case "Edm.Boolean": return typeof(bool);
        case "Edm.Decimal": return typeof(decimal);
        case "Edm.DateTime": return typeof (DateTime);                
        case "Edm.Guid": return typeof (Guid);

        default: throw new NotSupportedException("Not supported type " + type);
    }
}
```

To get the default value of a type, you could use the following. Again, code I have lying around that was initially taken from the following SO question: [Default value of a type at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490244/default-value-of-a-type-at-runtime)

```
object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
{
    if (t.IsValueType)
        return Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    return null;
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
var objectContext = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
var entitySet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<YOUR_ENTITY>().EntitySet;
var keys = entitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k =>
{
    var type = GetTypedEdmValue(k.TypeUsage.EdmType);                    
    return new
    {
        KeyName = k.Name,
        KeyType = type,
        KeyDefaultValue = GetDefaultValue(type)

    };
}).ToList();
```

This is just wired up for the sake of the example to return a list of anonymous types with key names, types and default values.

Comment: one question @LongboatHarry, does `EdmType` hold information about nullable? if so, is the type.Fullname will be different?

Comment: Not sure if the `EdmType` has that information - but certainly the `TypeUsage` on the relevant property has an `Identity` string that contains that information. For example, an `int?` property has `Identity` "Edm.Int32(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)". NOTE - the `DefaultValue` always appears to be an empty string (even for non-nullable types)